# How to control the range in a reciprocal function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given the reciprocal function $$\frac{a}{m \cdot x + b}$$ where $a,m,b$ are constants. I'm trying to figure out how/if I can control the range that this produces. The application of this problem is generating a "score" based on a locations' proximity to me. 
So for example, in my problem I know the range of possible values is $0$-$100$ km, I need to build a score between $1.0$ and $3.0$ where a proximity of $0$ km (i.e., very close) would generate a score closer to $3.0$ and a distance of $100$ km (i.e., very far away) would generate a score closer to $1.0$.

I was previously using this successfully to produced a range of $0$-$1.0$, but it turned out that I need greater control over the range produced.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "greater control over the range produced"? Why not just use a range from 0 to 1 and carry more digits of accuracy? I think a score of "0.851 out of 1" is much clearer than "2.4 on a scale of 1.0 to 3.0".

Comment: @AustinMohr It's not a person who is evaluating the score, its another program, and that program requires a score within said range.

Comment: Are you trying to *find* $a$, $m$, and $b$ so that you get the desired range, or do you have them already fixed and want to postprocess the output of the function to make it fit within the range?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \dfrac{a}{mx+b}$. Then for a score between the bounds $s_l$ (corresponding to $f(100)$) and $s_u$ (corresponding to f(0)), you can write:

$s(x) = s_u + \left[ (s_l-s_u) \cdot \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{f(100)-f(0)} \right]$

Comment: Multiplication is in general interpreted to have a higher precedence over addition; so your first multiply the two right-hand side terms.